Distinct countifs of IDs
I have the following table:



ID
Month num
Year




1
1
2024


1
1
2024


2
2
2024


1
2
2024


2
2
2024


2
2
2024


3
3
2024


1
1
2023



I am looking to get the unique count of IDs when the month num is equal or lower to the respective month and the year is 2024.
The outcome would look like:
January 2024: 1 distinct ID
February 2024: 2 distinct ID (because it is counting unique ID for Jan and Feb)
March 2024: 3 distinct IDs (because it is counting unique ID for Jan, Feb and March)

And so on
I am trying different formulas but I am not able to get the desired outcome. I tried countifs and sumproduct but nothing... I am not sure what i am doing wrong and this seems like a pretty easy formula.

I am trying different formulas, but I am not able to get the desired outcome. I tried countifs and sumproduct but nothing... I am not sure what i am doing wrong and this seems like a pretty easy formula.

Combination of COUNTA, UNIQUE and FILTER would do the trick:
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER($B$3:$B$10,($C$3:$C$10<=F3)*($D$3:$D$10=G3))))



FILTER is not working for me :(

What error do you get? Is formula not recognized in Excel?

Yes, probably because I have Office 2019

Just for convenience, insert a table (Table1) for the range containing data; hope you can do it in Excel 2019.
FREQUENCY could be used here I think. See Count unique values among duplicates - Microsoft Support.
For the Distinct Ids column (M below)
=SUM(IF(
FREQUENCY(
IF((Table1[Year]=J2)*(Table1[Month num]<=K2),Table1[ID],""),
IF((Table1[Year]=J2)*(Table1[Month num]<=K2),Table1[ID],"")
)>0,1))

Add columns for year and month, for convenience.




J
K
L
M




1
Year
Month
=CONCAT("Month ",K2," ",2024)
Distinct Ids


2
2024
1
Month 1 2024
1


3
2024
2
Month 2 2024
2


4
2024
3
Month 3 2024
3


5
2024
4
Month 4 2024
3


6
2023
1
Month 1 2024
1



